# SQL takes too long to spin up on first log in

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I  have a web site that runs on a standalone Server 2012 R2. I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on the same server which provides the backend storage and ASP Membership authentication.

The home page to the web site is a logon page. The entire site is secure. The home page loads plenty fast enough.

The issue is that SQL does not spin up fast enough and the page will eventually error out on first log in attempt.

Clicking the browser back arrow and enter password and login again and all is good and all queries run really fast.

The issue is only waking up SQL.

What is the best practice for preventing this??

Comment: MIght be a long shot but what power plan do you have?

Comment: Just by the fact I am not sure what you are referring to, I am hopeful this maybe an issue, how can I check it? If you are referring to the server, it is set to always on.

Comment: Are there specific settings for SQL, I have not found any.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/11/10/windows-server-2012-file-server-tip-switch-to-the-high-performance-power-profile.aspx

Comment: Do you mean "first log in after a server reboot", or "first log in attempt for every user on the site all the time"?

Comment: This would be a first logon after the server has not been active for a long while. Like the next morning's first logon, all subsequent access by any user is not an issue once SQL has spun up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I knew adding more RAM would help, but it has basically eliminated the issues all together. From 2GB to 8GB of RAM and the issue is completely gone. I also changed over to an SSD for better performance. Also had a VM with the same OS and SQL set up. It also runs much better with just 4GB.